# Локальная разработка и Telegram Login Widget

Tags: django, telegram

Есть ли возможность заставить работать Telegram Login Widget на локалхосте? Сделал простое джанго приложение, которое отдает шаблон с выданным мне JS кодом. Dev сервер запущен на адресе:порту `127.0.0.1:80`, в настройках бота указан домен `http://127.0.0.1`, `data-auth-url` указан тоже `http://127.0.0.1`.
При открытии странички, кнопка логина отображается с нужной аватаркой, но при нажатии в телеграмм приходит сообщение об успешном логине, но в браузере получаю ошибку **Bot domain invalid**. Как побороть эту ошибку? Или разработка на удаленном сервере единственный путь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Вместо `127.0.0.1` в настройках бота нужно указать любой локальный домен. Указал `localhost.local`, запустил локальный вебсервер на этот домене, все работает.

Просто `localhost` **BotFather** не дает вписать в качестве домена.